# Getting 404 error when submitting a form

Tags: forms, laravel, http-status-code-404

Routes:

```
Route::post('orders/edit-order-content/{$id}', 'Admin\OrderController@addProduct')->name('addProductToOrder');
Route::resource('/orders', 'Admin\OrderController');
```

Controller:

```
public function addProduct($id){
  dd($id);
}
```

View:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' =>['addProductToOrder',$order->id], 'id'=>'editOrderContent']) !!}
{!! Form::label('product_id','Product ID') !!}<br>
{!! Form::input('text','product_id') !!}<br>
{!! Form::label('qty','Quantity') !!}<br>
{!! Form::input('number','qty',1,['min'=>'1'])!!}<br>
{!! Form::submit('Add product',['class'=>'btn btn-info ','id'=>'addProduct']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Why am I getting 404 page? I tried to do it with new controller, but also got 404 error...

Comment: what route do you use?

Comment: Route::post('orders/edit-order-content/{$id}', 'Admin\OrderController@addProduct')->name('addProductToOrder');

Comment: you can alternatively use the url in form action {!! Form::open(['url' =>'orders/edit-order-content/' . $order->id, 'id'=>'editOrderContent']) !!}

Comment: @RahmanQaiser still getting 404 :c

Comment: So check your route sequence in route.php put your current route at the top of the other routes

Comment: @RahmanQaiser it is already at the top of the resource order

Comment: do you get anything when you do : return $id in your controller ?

Comment: What Laravel version are you using?

Comment: @GiamPy version 5.2

Comment: @Christophvh nah(

Comment: Replace `Route::post('orders/edit-order-content/{$id}', 'Admin\OrderController@addProduct')->name('addProductToOrder');` WITH `Route::post('orders/edit-order-content/{id}', 'Admin\OrderController@addProduct')->name('addProductToOrder');`

Comment: @BalrajAllam daym that worked, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the solutions is, you cannot use the `$` sign in your routes as a variable:

Replace

```
Route::post('orders/edit-order-content/{$id}', 'Admin\OrderController@addProduct')->name('addProductToOrder‌​');
```

With

```
 Route::post('orders/edit-order-content/{id}', 'Admin\OrderController@addProduct')->name('addProductToOrder‌​');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't chain `name()` on certain versions, I would recommend defining it explicitly.

```
Route::post('orders/edit-order-content/{$id}', [
    'uses'  =>'Admin\OrderController@addProduct',
    'as'=>'addProductToOrder'
]);
```

Also as mentioned in another answer, remove the `$`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are simply sending the form with get method instead of post.

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'post', 'route' =>['addProductToOrder',$order->id], 'id'=>'editOrderContent']) !!}
```